# Proof of uniqueness of positive cubes

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, axioms

Prove that there exists exactly one positive $t\in \mathbb{R}$ with $t^3=c$ for $c>0$.

I assume that most of my derivation needs to be algebraic and using some simple axioms.  So for example, if I define the set:

$$T:=\lbrace t\in \mathbb{R}: t> 0, t^3 \leq c \rbrace$$

I must show that the cubed root of $c$ is the supremum of $T$ and then prove its uniqueness.  But I'm not sure how to go about this.  How can I concisely prove this?

Comment: This really depends a lot on what you are allowed to assume.  If you are supposed to prove this directly from axioms for the real numbers, for instance, this will be pretty involved.  If you can use some basic facts about continuity, it's much easier.

Answer (score 3):

Uniqueness is pretty easy: if $0 < t < s$, then $t^3 < s^3$, so you cannot have two different $t, s > 0$ such that $t^3 = s^3 = c$.

For existence, let $s = \sup T$.

Assume by contradiction that $s^3 < c$. We will show that there is $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(s+\epsilon)^3 < c$, which contradicts the definition of $\sup T$.  Let $\Delta = c - s^3$. We have $\Delta > 0$ by assumption. We have

$$
(s+\epsilon)^3 = s^3 + 3 \epsilon s^2 + 3 \epsilon^2 s + \epsilon^3 = s^3 + \epsilon(3 s^2 + 3 \epsilon s + \epsilon^2)
$$

For $\epsilon < s$, $3s^2 + 3 \epsilon s + \epsilon^2 < 7 s^2$, so $(s+\epsilon)^3 = s^3 + \epsilon(3 s^2 + 3 \epsilon s + \epsilon^2) < s^3 + \epsilon \cdot 7 s^2$, so it's enough to pick $\epsilon$ such that $\epsilon < s$ and $\epsilon \cdot 7s^2 < \Delta$, that is, $\epsilon < \frac{\Delta}{7 s^2}$.

Thus, we obtained a contradiction, and therefore $s^3 \geq c$. We now need to prove that $s^3 \leq c$ to obtain $s^3 = c$. For this, we can use the same method as above: assume by contradiction that $s^3 > c$, and find $\epsilon > 0$ such that $(s-\epsilon)^3 > c$. This will show that $s - \epsilon$ is an upper bound of elements of $T$, and so $s - \epsilon \geq \sup T = s$, a contradiction. The argument is the same as above, with only minor changes.

Note that the argument above is basically about proving that $x \mapsto x^3$ is a continuous function.

Comment: I don't understand how your example works.  You say that $\Delta>0$, yet if $s^3<c$, then $\Delta$ must be less than 0.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I just don't understand why what you did works.

Comment: Oh, it's supposed to be the other way around, let me fix it.

Answer (score 2):

"At most one": if $t^3 = c = s^3$, then $t^3-s^3 = 0$ so $(t-s)(t^2+ts+s^2)=0$. Hence either $t=s$ or $t^2+ts+s^2 = 0$. But the latter is to say that $(t+s)^2 = ts$, or equivalently $t+s = \sqrt{ts}$ (this is valid since we are assuming $t, s$ are both positive), and this violates AM/GM because $t, s > 0$.

"At least one": this is just from the intermediate value theorem, taking $x \mapsto x^3$ for $x$ between $0$ and $c$ (if $c \geq 1$), or taking $x \mapsto x^3$ for $x$ between $0$ and $1$ (if $c < 1$).

Comment: Uniqueness can be proved much simpler: if $0 < t < s$, then $t^3 < s^3$, so you cannot have two different $t, s > 0$ such that $t^3 = s^3 = c$.

Comment: Fair enough; I just started writing and kept going until I hit the end, and then stopped :)

Comment: A little simpler (two ways): $t^2+ts+s^2 = \frac12(t^2+s^2+(t+s)^2)=(t+s/2)^2+3s^2/4$.  I prefer the first because it is symmetrical, but either will do.

Answer (score 1):

If $f(t) = t^3$
and
$f(t_1) = f(t_2)
= c$
with $c > 0$,
then,
by the mean value theorem,
there is a $t_0$
with
$0 < t_1 \le t_0 \le t_2$
with
$f'(t_0) = 0$.

But
$f'(t) = 3t^2$
so that
$f'(t_0) = 0$
implies that
$t_0 = 0$
which contradicts
$0 < t_1 \le t_0 \le t_2$.